# Will TCL L32S5200 support TP Link WN722N?

Tags: usb

I have TCL TV Model No. L32S5200 whose wifi is not working. I've got a Tp link WN722N usb wifi adapter. Will the tv support it? Or should I consult a technician's help

I tried resetting the TV to resolve the wifi issue in the TV but it didn't work